# How to create select option in LWC?

Tags: javascript, html, lightning-web-components, selectoption

I am creating a select option in LWC. From server side controller I am returning list of wrapper having key and value as below-

> [{"key":"All Accounts","value":"00B7F000006l0B3UAI"}]

I the html file I am creating options using iteration as below. -

```
<select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
     <template for:each = {listViews} for:item="listViewItem">
        <option value={listViewItem.key}>{listViewItem.value}</option>
     </template>
</select>
```

Although, I am able to display data on the markup but But I am getting compilation error when I use it with the select option-

> Missing key for element  inside of iterator. Elements within iterators must have a unique, computed key value.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you use `for:each` you have to use `key` attribute in the child markup. If not it gives a compilation error.

From [SF Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/migrate_iterations):

> Note that you must use a key to assign a unique value to each item in
> the list.

```
<select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
     <template for:each = {listViews} for:item="listViewItem">
        <option key={listViewItem.key} value={listViewItem.key}>{listViewItem.value}</option>
     </template>
</select>
```

Comment: It worked for me. This is the reason i like this platform.  Thanks Pranay!!

Comment: How to make any option is selected? among n number of option ,i need one value should be marked as selected

Answer (score 3):

For creating select list drop down in LWC, we may also use [lightning-combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example).